# Juju - Add-unit vs deploy

Tags: juju, maas

What is the difference between `deploy` and `add-unit` in `juju`?

For example when I execute `juju deploy wordpress` and `juju add-unit wordpress`, both of the commands pick up a machine to PXE boot and install the OS and the charm. So are they (`deploy` and `add-unit`) the same thing?

Comment: There is some difference like there is no constraints flag for the `juju add-unit` command. Check [this](https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.20/charms-deploying) and [this](https://jujucharms.com/docs/1.20/charms-constraints)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use deploy when the service doesn't exist yet. You use add-unit when the service already exists.